# N-Layer Architecture in C#

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer, n-layer

I'm trying to implement N-layer architecture to my project first time.

I created BLL, DAL and GUI

Here is in GUI

```
XmlSettingsBLL xmlSettings = new XmlSettingsBLL();

  var newDict = new NewDictionary()
  {
   StrDataSourceType = "AccessMdb",// DataSourceType.AccessMdb,
   DictionaryID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
   FirstColumnName = "Kelime",
   SecondColumnName = "Karsilik",
   TableName = "kelimelerpro",
   LastShowedID = 0,
   Name = "kpds",
   Path = "kelimeler.mdb"
  };

  xmlSettings.AddNewDictionary(newDict);
```

here is in BLL

```
public bool AddNewDictionary(NewDictionary list)
{
list.DatasourceType = (DataSourceType)Enum.Parse(typeof (DataSourceType), list.StrDataSourceType);

IDictionaryList newDictionary =list;

try
{
   helper.AddDictionary(newDictionary);
   return true;
}
catch
{
  return false;
}      
}

 public class NewDictionary : IDictionaryList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DictionaryID { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int LastShowedID { get; set; }
    public string FirstColumnName { get; set; }
    public string SecondColumnName { get; set; }
    public DataSourceType DatasourceType { get; set; }
    public string StrDataSourceType { get; set; }  
}
```

and here is in DAL

```
 public void AddDictionary(IDictionaryList list)
 {
   var channelElem = xdoc.Element("MemorizeSettings");
   var dictionaries = channelElem.Element("Dictionaries"); 

   XAttribute[] attrs = new XAttribute[8];
   attrs[0] = new XAttribute("Name", list.Name);
   attrs[1] = new XAttribute("Path", list.Path);
   attrs[2] = new XAttribute("TableName", list.TableName);
   attrs[3] = new XAttribute("DatasourceType", Enum.GetName(typeof(DataSourceType),list.DatasourceType));
   attrs[4] = new XAttribute("LastShowedID", "0");
   attrs[5] = new XAttribute("FirstColumnName", list.FirstColumnName);
   attrs[6] = new XAttribute("SecondColumnName", list.SecondColumnName);
   attrs[7] = new XAttribute("DictionaryID", list.DictionaryID);

   var newdict = new XElement("Dictionary", attrs);

   dictionaries.Add(newdict);
   xdoc.Save(fileName);
 }

public interface IDictionaryList
{
     string Name { get; set; }
     string Path { get; set; }
     string DictionaryID { get; set; }
     string TableName { get; set; }
     int LastShowedID { get; set; }
     string FirstColumnName { get; set; }
     string SecondColumnName { get; set; }
     DataSourceType DatasourceType { get; set; }
}
```

so, in GUI, naturally it needs to add DAL as reference because I derived NewDictionary  from IDictionary that is in DAL. But I want to seperare GUI and DAL each other.

apart from creating an IDictionary object, how can I do it?
I hope the question is clear

Comment: Whats the problem with deriving from IDictionaryList? If its a referencing problem, just move your contract interfaces to another project; like core/framework or base

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I dont want to do like that way. I am looking for how I dont need add reference/move the interface to my gui project.. Otherwise, I could already do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the condition that neither can reference each other, and no 3rd party reference of contracts; the only logical solution is to deal with it as a change in domain. You could use a DataContract and a DataContractSerialiser to help you.

[Serialiser borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010191/using-datacontractserializer-to-serialize-but-cant-deserialize-back)

```
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(), null);
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
            return serializer.ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }
```

here you have effectively the same object defined in (pretend) two libraries.. FooA and FooB

```
    [DataContract(Name="Foo")]
    public class FooA
    {
        [DataMember] 
        public int Value;
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Foo")]
    public class FooB
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Value;
    }

    static public void Main()
    {
        var fooA = new FooA() {Value = 42};

        var serialised = Serialize(fooA);

        // Cross domain

        var fooB = (FooB) Deserialize(serialised, typeof(FooB));

        Console.WriteLine(fooB.Value);

    }
```

Look up [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms733127.aspx)

> A data contract is a formal agreement between a service and a client
>   that abstractly describes the data to be exchanged. That is, to
>   communicate, the client and the service do not have to share the same
>   types, only the same data contracts. A data contract precisely
>   defines, for each parameter or return type, what data is serialized
>   (turned into XML) to be exchanged.