# WCF deserialization with XmlEnumAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-attribute

Enum is automatically deserialized by the WCF service.

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://rca.ws.emitere/2010-11/")]
public enum Animal
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Cat name")]
    Cat,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Dog name")]
    Dog

}
```

Using

```
XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Animal anim{ get; set; }
```

Can I set the default value, when no match is correct? Right now it generates a serialization error.

I want to return a validation message without changing the wsdl. The web service has several methods and for each of them one should return another message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you are trapped in using enum in WCF contract.
One option that can work for you is to change type of property `anim` to `String` and add other property attributed by `XmlIgnore` that will contain your desired value after deserialization is completed.
Please remember that by this you might have to consider the same "value transfer" for serialization as well.

Let's suppose `anim` property is contained in:

```
public class Zoo
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Animal? animAsEnum { get; set; }

    public string anim { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Animal animAsEnum;
        if (Enum.TryParse(anim, out animAsEnum))
        {
            this.animAsEnum = animAsEnum;
        }
    }
}
```

How it works can be demonstrated as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Zoo_Cateau()
{
    string input = "<Zoo xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
        + "xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UnitTestProject3\">"
        + "<anim>Cateau</anim></Zoo>";

    Zoo target = Deserialize<Zoo>(input);
    Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    Assert.AreEqual("Cateau", target.anim);
    Assert.IsNull(target.animAsEnum);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Zoo_Cat()
{
    string input = "<Zoo xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
        + "xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UnitTestProject3\">"
        + "<anim>Cat</anim></Zoo>";

    Zoo target = Deserialize<Zoo>(input);
    Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    Assert.AreEqual("Cat", target.anim);
    Assert.AreEqual(Animal.Cat, target.animAsEnum);
}
```

Where `Deserialize<T>` method is taken from [Using DataContractSerializer to serialize, but can't deserialize back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010191/using-datacontractserializer-to-serialize-but-cant-deserialize-back/8698753#8698753)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution changes wsdl, and j use MessageContract which does not support OnDeserialized.

Comment: If the values of enum from the server are not falling into the range defined by enum Animal {} then you are using outdated WSDL, couldn't you just get the up to date WSDL and regenerate your client classes?

Comment: WSDL is just definition how to generate server or client classes - it affects only indirectly the data that can be deserialized - please note that in TestMethod Zoo_Cat() you could deserialize class YourOrginalClass { public Anilmal anim{ get; set; } } too without any problem.

Comment: OnDeserialized is general functionality not directly related to specific MessageContract, do you confirm, you use WCF?